# How can I post to my wall while tagging some friends via Facebook C# SDK (5.1.1)?

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to post on the user's wall while tagging a few of his/her friends in it (up to 8 people). Another option is to post on these 8 friends' wall instead.

I used the example given here -
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/#publishing

And I tried to add "to" section to it (based on what I saw in Facebook Open Graph API) with no luck. Trying to change posting to .Post("[fbid]/feed") didn't work as well. It just posted on my wall instead.

What am I doing wrong? can someone publish a full example?

Answer (score 0):

The Graph API does not currently support tagging users in posts, although it has been [requested as a feature](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=9441).  You could make 8 different wall posts but there is a chance that you application will get disabled for too many wall posts if enough users hide your application or mark it as spam.  But to do it, you just do an HTTP POST to /**friendId**/feed.